# Referencing Asynchronous F# datatype from C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#

I created a F# library that returns this datatype

```
FSharpAsync<IEnumerable<Tupel<DateTime,string>>>
```

How do I access the `FSharpAsync` type so I can enumerate through the tuple from C# and print out the content?

Comment: I personally don't prefer to expose FSharp data types like FSharpAsync in a library written in F#. Could you please post the F# code so that we can propose a better way to expose the Fsharp library

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is generally not recommended to expose F# types such as `FSharpAsync` in a public interface that will be used by C# clients (see [F# component design guidelines](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf)). You can use `Async.StartAsTask` (on the F# side) to expose the operation as a `Task<T>` that is easy to use from C#.

In fact, I would also replace the tuple with a named type (that captures the meaning of the data structure). Tuples can be used in C#, but they are not idiomatic in C#:

```
// Assuming you have an operation like this 
let asyncDoWork () : Async<seq<DateTime * string>> = (...)

// Define a named type that explains what the date-string pair means
type Item(created:DateTime, name:string) =
  member x.Created = created
  member x.Name = name

// Create a simple wrapper that wraps values into 'Item' type
let asyncDoWorkItems () = 
  async { let! res = asyncDoWork()
          return seq { for (d, n) in res -> Item(d, n) } }
```

Now, to expose the operation to C#, the best practice is to use a type with an overloaded static method. The method starts the operation as a task and one overload specifies cancellation token. The C# naming convention for these is to add `Async` to the *end* of the name (which doesn't overlap with F# which adds `Async` to the front):

```
type Work = 
  static member DoWorkAsync() =
    Async.StartAsTask(asyncDoWorkItems())
  static member DoWorkAsync(cancellationToken) =
    Async.StartAsTask(asyncDoWorkItems(), cancellationToken = cancellationToken)
```

Your C# code can then use `Work.DoWorkAsync()` and work with the task in the usual C# style. It will even work with the `await` keyword that will be (probably) added to C# 5.

Answer (score 4):

Reference FSharp.Core.dll, then:

```
FSharpAsync<IEnumerable<Tupel<DateTime,string>>> async = ...
IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, string>> result = FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously(async, timeout: FSharpOption<int>.None, cancellationToken: FSharpOption<CancellationToken>.None);
```

`FSharpAsync` is in the `Microsoft.FSharp.Control` namespace.

`FSharpOption` is in the `Microsoft.FSharp.Core` namespace.

Comment: @costa : it does, yes. This answer is from 2012. I think recent versions of F# have made compatibility between FSharpAsync and Tasks easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate it via the static methods of [FSharpAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370232.aspx). The `async` you're getting is likely of type `Async<'T>`, which has no instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the return type `FSharpAsync<IEnumerable<Tupel<DateTime,string>>>` this tell us that it is a async operation that when gets executed by the static methods in FSharpAsync will return a `IEnumerable<Tupel<DateTime,string>>`, so this becomes a case where the F# library create a operation (the async operation) that your C# code can execute, so it act as lazy operation that you can execute later after getting it from F# library and when you execute this lazy operation it returns you a IEnumerable which it self is sort of lazy in the sense that you pull values from it and at the same times the values are generated.

I think you can just return then `IEnumerable<Tupel<DateTime,string>>` from your F# library and doesn't need to return Async operation at all. But again this depends on what your F# library does and how it is supposed to generate this IEnumerable