# C#: how to implement as "async" and "!" in F#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#, callback, aop

Reading F# recently, it turns out to me that "async" and "!" (Bang! :p) are quite useful features. (Off topic, this is an example that programming language is not only an academic research topic, but a real-life, productivity design topic).

Below is from Luca Bolognese's PDC 2008 presentation:

```
let internal loadPrices ticker = async {
    let url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + ticker + "&d=9&e=30&f=2008&g=d&a=2&b=13&c=1986&ignore=.csv"
    let req = WebRequest.Create(url)
    let! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse() //athos: need F# Powerpack

    let stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
    let reader = new StreamReader(stream)
    let! csv = reader.AsyncReadToEnd()

    let prices =
        csv.Split([|'\n'|])
        |> Seq.skip 1
        |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Split([|','|]))
        |> Seq.filter (fun values -> values |> Seq.length = 7)
        |> Seq.map (fun values ->
        System.DateTime.Parse(values.[0]),
        float values.[6])    

    return prices }
```

The charming part is, callback is handled gracefully: Programmers don't need to take care of BackgroundWorker or Theads' Join().

So, in C#, is there a graceful solution, to implement F# "aync" and "!" features?
For example, is it possible to do an "async...run...callback" as below or in a similar effortless way?

```
public void GetApplicationSettings()
{ 
    async(objAsyncRunner = new System.Async.Runner() ) //similar to "using" in C#
    run // similar to "if" in C#
    {
        string url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + ticker + "&d=9&e=30&f=2008&g=d&a=2&b=13&c=1986&ignore=.csv"
        var req = WebRequest.Create(url);
        var resp = req.AsyncGetResponse();
    }
    callback run // similar to "if else" in C#
    {
        var stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var csv = reader.AsyncReadToEnd();
    }
    callback // similar to "else" in C#
    {
        var prices = csv.Split('\n').....;
    }
}
```

ps. I know some you guys will say: athos, just use F#!
yeah... i'm not against F# but it needs time to change the whole department, before that i hope to borrow some merits from F#.

I know there are some Aspect programming concept to extend C# feature. However it still has not reached F# level.

For example, I can extend PostSharp from http://www.sharpcrafters.com , so that by simple assigning an attribute to a method, to force it run in a dedicated thread asynchronously:

```
[RunInADedicatedThread(Async = true)]
public void GetApplicationSettings()
{ ... }
```

provided the attribute is prepared:

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class )]
[MulticastAttributeUsage( MulticastTargets.Method )]
public sealed class RunInADedicatedThreadAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
// MethodInterceptionAspect is extending PostSharp
{
    public bool Async { get; set; }

    public override void OnInvoke( MethodInterceptionArgs args )
    {
        if (Async)
        {
            //MyThreadPool is my extention for PostSharp 
            MyThreadPool.GetThread().ExecuteAsync(
                () =>
                    {
                        args.Proceed();
                    } );
            return;
        }
        MyThreadPool.GetThread().Execute( args.Proceed );
    }
}
```

This helps a bit, but it's still not F# level:

> - the "run in a dedicated thread, asynchronously" requests are not defined on the calling, but on the method GetApplicationSettings() itself! This method might as well be renamed to GetApplicationSettingsAsynchronously(), isn't it;
> - also, this can't help the callback part;
> - let alone the F# "async" feature to use less threads ... i can even drop this "advaced" feature for now...

Comment: to ease asynchronous coding in C#...

Comment: athos: I think you'd be interested in [C# & .NET 5.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/28/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-one.aspx)

Comment: @Alastair : thanks, let me digest it.. I wonder when will C# release?

Comment: there is a CTP available for testing, my guess for the full release is sometime next year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Brian already mentioned, [Visual Studio Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx) is what you're looking for. It adds something like asynchronous workflows to a future version of C#. It adds `async` methods that are just like *asynchronous workflows* in F# and `await` keyword that behaves like `let!`. There are a few differences between the two and I wrote a [series of articles that compares them](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-fsharp-async-intro.aspx).

Unfortunately, the async support in C# is still a CTP. If you want to write production quality asynchronous code, than the best option is to write it in F# and reference it from C# using `Tasks`. This [SO question discusses how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811072/referencing-asynchronous-f-datatype-from-c).

You can simulate something like `async` in C# in various ways. Brian mentioned using LINQ (in his blog post), but that's quite limited. I think that using iterators is more flexible. Here is a sample from an [article that does exactly that](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async.aspx):

```
static IEnumerable<IAsync> DownloadAsync(string url)
{
  WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
  Async<WebResponse> response = req.GetResponseAsync();
  yield return response;

  Stream resp = response.Result.GetResponseStream();
  Async<string> html = resp.ReadToEndAsync().ExecuteAsync<string>();
  yield return html;

  Console.WriteLine(html.Result);
}
```

This works similarly to `async workflows`, because C# iterators are also compiled as a state machine. Jeffrey Richter's [`AsyncEnumerator` implements a more complete API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546608.aspx) based on this idea.

Answer (score 2):

See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx

and

http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/an-introduction-to-async-workflows-in-f-or-how-to-utilize-all-those-cpus-without-writing-lots-of-threading-code-part-three/

for useful info.  The first link is a CTP to 'async' for C# and VB (to come in a future version of those languages), and the second shows a way to leverage LINQ today to do async in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the same function in C# using [FSharpx](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx), which looks pretty much the same as the F# version:

```
FSharpAsync<IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, decimal>>> LoadPrices(string ticker) {
    var url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + ticker + "&d=9&e=30&f=2008&g=d&a=2&b=13&c=1986&ignore=.csv";
    var req = WebRequest.Create(url);
    return
        from resp in req.FSharpAsyncGetResponse()
        let stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
        let reader = new StreamReader(stream)
        from csv in reader.FSharpAsyncReadToEnd()
        select (from line in csv.Split('\n').Skip(1)
                let values = line.Split(',')
                where values.Length == 7
                select Tuple.Create(DateTime.Parse(values[0]), decimal.Parse(values[6], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var price = LoadPrices("MSFT").Run().First();
Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2008,10,30), price.Item1);
Assert.AreEqual(20.82m, price.Item2);
```

The key concept here is that LINQ is more than just language integrated *queries*: it's language integrated *monads*. FSharpx simply implements the bindings required to access F# async from LINQ in C# / VB.NET, and [it's pretty trivial code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/CSharpCompat.fs).

FSharpx requires .NET 3.5 or better, but in principle you could make this work on C# 3, .NET 2.0.

One of the downsides is that there is no `use!` (which should have been used in the original F# code too) in LINQ, so managing disposables is problematic.