# Windows Store Apps and F#

Tags: f#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to create a portable library using F# to use with Windows Store apps. I created one fs file with one class:

```
module FunctionalRT

open System.Net
open System.IO

type WebHelper =

    static member DownloadStringAsync (url:string) = async {
        let req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()
        use stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
        let reader = new StreamReader(stream) 
        let s = reader.ReadToEnd()
        return s
    }
```

I referenced this library in my Windows Store app with no problems. But the problem is, I cannot access the `FunctionalRT` module neither the `WebHelper` class. When I write `using FunctionalRT` or try to use `FunctionalRT.WebHelper.FunctionalRT`, the compiler complains it does not know it. What may be the problem?

**EDIT:**
After a few buidls and cleans I get

```
The type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=2.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.  C:\Users\Igor\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\App3\App3\GroupedItemsPage.xaml.cs  46  13  App3
```

**EDIT:**

Adding a reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\..\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\.NETPortable\FSharp.Core.dll` solved the above error message, but there is another one

```
Cannot await 'Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync<string>'
```

Comment: Did you make sure all your references (both .Net and 3rd party) are WinRT-compatible?

Comment: There are just 2 projects: Windows 8 app (App3) and F# Portable Library (FunctionalRT with Target framework: .NET for Windows Store Apps, .NET Framework 4.5, Silverlight 5) and App3 has a referebce to FunctionalRT

Comment: I believe the error message says that the C# project should also reference FSharp.Core (WinRT version, of course). I'm assuming right now only the F# project references FSharp.Core? If I am correct, this error would also appear when writing a regular C#-F# application.

Comment: I had the same thought but there seems to be no way to add the Fsharp.Core reference in the Add reference dialog, except maybe for browsing for the DLL

Comment: Then browse away! (that's what I sometimes do, but I think it should always appear on the list - maybe there is an issue with the WinRT GAC).

Comment: @RamonSnir I added the reference by hand to the same DLL as in the F# Portable Library projects but now I get another error. I updated my question.

Comment: Before SO kicks us out of here, please remember that F# Async is not fully compatible with the new C# async. Google has plenty of articles about the interoperation of F# and C#, including async.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to reference this library in your Windows Store app to make it work:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime.NETPortable\FSharp.Core.dll

And regarding that FSharpAsync class, see this thread:
[Referencing Asynchronous F# datatype from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811072/referencing-asynchronous-f-datatype-from-c-sharp)

You could use static method of the FSharpAsync type for awaiting the returned object.

Comment: I figured out the firt part but thanks for the link, it helped

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling this code from C#, it would probably integrate better like this:

```
static member DownloadStringAsync (url:string) = async {
    let req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
    use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()
    use stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
    let reader = new StreamReader(stream) 
    let s = reader.ReadToEnd()
    return s
} |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Then your C# project will not need to reference FSharp.Core, and you can use the standard C# `await` keyword just as if you were calling C# async code.