# Referencing F# libraries from a Windows Store/Metro C# app

Tags: c#, f#, microsoft-metro, windows-store

I'm attempting to do some [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) in F#. SharpDX can't be imported into a Portable Library, only into a standard .NET library.

Having worked around [a glaring bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/761306/cannot-add-reference-to-portable-f-library-from-portable-c-library#tabs) to reference the F# library from the C# app, I now run into another problem upon execution:

`Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

This is a familiar exception, but I don't know what would be causing it in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13097092/636019), it's possibly the same issue.

Comment: @ildjarn Darn, nope, that's not it.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can only reference F# Portable Libraries in Windows Store projects, not regular f# dlls, that's the first thing.
The second, as the error says - you have to reference the FSharp.Core library. It's located here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime.NETPortable\FSharp.Core.dll

I have answered similar question here with more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13064798/574062

Comment: The thing is, Portable Libraries don't have access to as much libraries, including WinRT builds of SharpDX for instance. There's a "Class Library (Windows Store)" for C#, but nothing like that for F#.

Comment: Also, I've tried adding several versions of FSharp.Core.dll to the app's references -- no go.

Comment: That's another problem, Portable Libraries in F# have fixed set of supported frameworks and sadly you cannot access Windows Store specific API in there.

Comment: Well that's just great. I don't know what they hope to accomplish with all this fragmentation. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Portable Class Libraries are good but are restricted to APIs that are supported on all platforms that you declare when you create the project. It's not really "fragmentation" as much as the cold fact that PCLs must only contain references that are truly portable.

Comment: @JustinSkiles .NET class libraries have been split into Windows Store Class Libraries (which only work with Metro aka Modern aka Store aka WinRT, not to be confused with Windows RT), Portable Class Libraries (which work on Metro, desktop and mobile, but aren't compatible with Windows Store libaries or .NET Class Libraries), and .NET Class Libraries (which only work on desktop). *That's* fragmentation, and the result here of that fragmentation is that F#, which can't be used to write Windows Store Class Libraries, have no access to other Windows Store Class Libraries -- of which there are many.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka What you just said in no way disagrees with my comment.

Comment: @JustinSkiles I said it's fragmentation; you said it's not.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka You're describing new library types of which do not actually inherit from the original ".NET Class Library" type. Windows Store Class Libraries target a subset of the .NET framework (.NET for Windows Store) and PCLs target whatever you choose. By your logic, the introduction of any new library type is "fragmentation." Their design decisions with creating the new framework is documented in //build sessions and MSDN.

Comment: @JustinSKiles I've watched most of the //build videos and read most of the documentation on MSDN. Yes, it's fragmentation. Sometimes it's necessary and it's good, sometimes it's more bad than good, but it's still fragmentation. This is definitely fragmentation for the worse.

Comment: Even worse... it turns out that F# "Portable" Libraries also can't be used with Windows Phone.